# On boundedness of decreasing function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $W: \mathbb R^n \to\mathbb R$ be a continuously differentiable function. Suppose $W(x)$ is decreasing. Is $W(x)$ bounded above?!

Comment: What does "decreasing" mean for a function on $\mathbb R^n$?

Answer (score 3):

Why should it be?  It is already false with $n=1$:  take $f(x)=-x$ or $f(x) = -x^3$ or...